# how to convert node_uri (array) to url string

Tags: nodes, uri

I used a function node_uri($node) get an url array. how to change it to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path string is contained inside the `path` element of that array, so

```
$node = node_load(1);
$uri_array = node_uri($node);

$url = url($uri_array['path']);
```

should get you what you're looking for